# Секунд или минут?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

Как будет правильнее (если учитывать, что *03* — это минуты, а *51* — это секунды): *ты написал этот текст за 03:51 **сек.*** или *ты написал этот текст за 03:51 **мин.***?
То есть, какую единицу измерения времени нужно поставить после чисел? Или же вообще воздержаться от этого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно будет "за 3 мин. 51 сек."

Answer (score 0):

Форматы с двоеточием (типа HH:MM:SS) используются для обозначения **времени суток**. **Временной интервал** нужно обозначать так: *3 мин. 51 сек.*, или *231 сек.*, или *3,85 мин.* (три целых восемьдесят пять десятых минуты).

Answer (score -2):

Никита, по-моему, важно, что именно Вы хотите написать.

Если Вы имеете в виду три целых пятьдесят одну сотую секунды, то напишите - 03:51 сек., если же речь идёт о трёх минутах и пятидесяти одной секунде , то запись должна быть такая - 03:51 мин.